# QGIS creates gaps while generating tiles from line features with Write vector tiles (XYZ)

Tags: qgis, vector-tiles, vector-tile-package

I try to generate vector tiles from a roads network layer, but it generates big gaps between features. It seems that some segments of the lines are being erased, while polygons and points are generated perfectly. I am using the native QGIS `Write Vector Tiles (XYZ)` geoprocessing tool.

[image]